# how to use jquery proxy hand event object

Tags: jquery, proxy

my code http://jsfiddle.net/4Ub95/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="libs/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
  <script>


  $(function(){

  var getid = function(){
      // 
      // I want this is $("#test") obj
      // jQuery.proxy used for?
      var id =  $(this).attr('data-id');
      alert(id);
   }

  $("#test").click(function(){
    //not worki
    //show undefined 
    $.proxy(this.funa,this)()
  })


  })
  </script>

  <button id="test" data-id="123">Click</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I want this is $("#test") 
want get attr data-id use proxy..
but the code not work
how to use proxy method for event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed the wrong function name,

```
 $.proxy(getid,this)()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ub95/1/